# Non blocking reads with Julia

Tags: multithreading, io, julia, getch

I would like to read an user input without blocking the main thread, much like the `getch()` function from `conio.h`. Is it possible in Julia?

I tried with `@async` but it looked like my input wasn't being read although the main thread wasn't blocked.

Comment: like `read(STDIN,Char)` ?(https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/networking-and-streams/#Basic-Stream-I/O-1)

Comment: @FelipeLema `read(STDIN, Char)` still needs an "enter" to understand the input. I'm looking for something like `getch()` cause there's a lot of things happening and I can't block the execution waiting the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, I believe, is either you are running on global scope which makes `@async` create its own local variables (when it reads, it reads into a variable in another scope) or you are using an old version of Julia.

The following examples read an integer from `STDIN` in a non-blocking fashion.

```
function foo()
    a = 0
    @async a = parse(Int64, readline())
    println("See, it is not blocking!")
    while (a == 0)
        print("")
    end
    println(a)
end
```

The following two examples do the job in global scope, using an array. You can do the same trick with other types mutable objects. 
Array example:

```
function nonblocking_readInt()
    arr = [0]
    @async arr[1] = parse(Int64, readline())
    arr
end

r = nonblocking_readInt() # is an array
println("See, it is not blocking!")
while(r[1] == 0) # sentinel value check
    print("")
end
println(r[1])
```

Comment: Note that the `print("")` statement is necessary, or this will be stuck in the `while` loop forever.  If anyone more knowledgeable could explain why the print statement is required, that would be greatly appreciated!